# Doing mathematical research alone.

Tags: education, research

Currently I am no researcher in mathematics, but in the future I might consider becoming one. Before that, I want to know, out of my curiosity, that whether anyone can perform mathematical research alone or not. From what I have observed people who are involved in any kind of research read many papers from google scholars and journals like springer verlag, elsevier ,etc, so will I be fruitful in independent research if I fully dedicate my work through these resources. Also after getting any significant result in mathematical research where should one send his/her work to get it recognised and verified. Thank you.